# Why are my textures mirrored?

Tags: texturing, uv

I was adding some textures in the UV unwrapping tab when the texture I was adding was reflected backwards. how can I fix it? I've tried rotating it but obviously that didn't work...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Instead of rotating it, scale the uv island to minus 1 on the x axis.

Comment: if Alexandres comment doesn't help (but i think it does) pls provide blend file

Answer (score 2):

Your UV maps are flipped and it makes the texture look as if you were looking at it from the backface :

[image]

I know of two ways you can fix this :

The first one is, as @Alexandre mentioned, by fixing the UV directly. It should be the one you pick since, having a flipped UV is generally a bad idea :

Just select the face(s) that have the flipped textures, go to the UV editor, select everything and press <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>-</kbd> then <kbd>1</kbd> and it should display your texture the way it should be.

The second way is kind of a quick fix but I think it's still good to know since it illustrates the usage of the `Mapping` node. Chances are that you are already using a  `Mapping` node with your image texture in the node editor but if you haven't already, you can plug a `Mapping` and a `Texture Coordinate` node to your Image texture like so (You can do this by selecting the image texture and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> if you have Node Wrangler add-on activated):

[image]

You can use the `Scale` option of this node to change the scale of your texture. Setting the `Scale`'s `X` to `-1` should solve your problem.

**Notes**

I started from the assumption that your texture is horizontal so if the steps I gave didn't fix the problem, you should check if it's not the Y axis that needs to be flipped instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys i've fixed it now

Comment: @Michael Ciurleo if the answer is correct you can validate it (check icon on the top right of the answer)